# What about c code snippet in questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Numerous online competition websites feature an online c   compiler, how about having one for code snippet in the questions as well, as it is available for HTML/Javascript currently? It would support better understanding of problem by everyone. It might also help in rooting out questions with silly codes..so feature request is: "c   code snippet" ..

Comment: You probably want the same for C, ruby, python, perl, pascal, C#, lua, ... too. Naturally, for those where it makes a difference, you also want to choose the underlying platform. See the problem yet?

Comment: Which computer would run the code? Html is _sort of_ safe. I sure as hell don't want c++ code running on _my_ computer!

Comment: You have to realize that every single user of the site is accessing the site through an HTML/JavaScript development environment with all of the necessary tools to build and run the application, built in security (well, mostly), etc.  All of that would have to be built from scratch in every single language that *doesn't* run naively in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of online compilers one can use if you want to run the code.  In fact the [C++ Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info) has a list of them.  SO integrating this is not needed.

Comment: Especially these online compilers can be used specifying specific versions, and flavors. There's actually a good list in the c++ tag wiki info.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have tag wiki linked in my post to direct the people to it.

Comment: Ooops, didn't spot it at a 1st glance. Upvoted your answer anyway.